# Get posts by Model's followings

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

followers_table:

```
    Schema::create(config('follow.followables_table', 'followables'), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->morphs('follower');
        $table->morphs('followable');
        $table->timestamp('accepted_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index(['followable_type', 'accepted_at']);
    });
```

Status:

```
    Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->morphs('owner');
        $table->string('post')
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am trying to get the 'followers' statuses:

```
    $followers = $model->followers()->pluck('followable_id', 'followable_type');

    return $query->where(function ($query) use($followers) {
        $query->whereIn('statuses.owner_id', $followers);
        $query->whereIn('statuses.owner_type', $followers);
    });
```

But that returns nothing... So to clarify:

I want to get all statuses where:

```
followables.followable_id = statuses.owner_id
followables.followable_type = statuses.owner_type

from `$followers`
```

$model = User::class

relationships:

User:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
 */
public function statuses(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Status::class, 'owner');
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
 */
public function followers(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Followers::class, 'followers');
}
```

This is a scope on statuses that I use with other scopes:
This is a scope on statuses that I use with other scopes:
This is a scope on statuses that I use with other scopes:

```
    /**
     * Scope a query to followers statuses.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeFollowers(Builder $query, Model $model): Builder
    {
//        $followers = $model->followers()->pluck('followable_id', 'followable_type');
//
//        return $query->where(function ($query) use($followers) {
//            $query->whereIn('statuses.owner_id', $followers);
//            $query->whereIn('statuses.owner_type', $followers);
//        });

        $followers = $model->followers()->pluck('followable_id', 'followable_type');

        $n = $query->whereIn(['statuses.owner_id', 'statuses.owner_type'], $followers);

        dd($n->get());
    }
```

Comment: Are there relationships between the models? Why do you need to do a manual query? What is `$models` in your code fragment?

Comment: For this instance $model = User::class, I'll update the relationship above.

Comment: This isn't super clear but seems like you want `$model->followers()->with('statuses')`?

Comment: Also note that you aren't actually executing a query in your code. You're just running `where()` on whatever `$query` is and returning that. Are you expecting a `get()` at the end perhaps?

Comment: Yes, but also merged with `$model->statuses()`  if that makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, this is a scope on Status::class (see updated post)